# How to add a new numerical (string) key and shift the rest by +1 without breaking reactivity in Vuejs data

Tags: javascript, php, json, vue.js, vue-component

I have a Vue component that builds the below into a blog form field. The writer is allowed to creatively add/slot any field of choice in between each other when building a blog post ...(like: title, paragraph, blockquote, image) in an object like:

```
{"post":{"1":{"title":{"name":"","intro":""}},"2":{"paragraph":{"text":"","fontweight":"default-weight","bottommargin":"default-bottom-margin"}},"3":{"image":{"class":"default-image-class","creditto":""}},"4":{"subheading":{"text":"","size":"default"}}}};
```

I've tried using jQuery each to iterate and add it up into a makedo "dataObj" object and inject it back on the data:

```
 data: {  treeData: myUserData.post },

injectFieldType: function(type, position){

            var storeObj = {};
            var dataObj = this.treeData;
            var crntKey;

            $.each( dataObj, function( key, value ) {

                  if(key < position)
                    {
                        //remain same as key is not to change
                    }

                    else if(key == position)
                    {
                        dataObj[''+(parseInt(key)+1)] = dataObj[key];   /*push key further right with +1*/
                        dataObj[key] = /*add injected field here*/;
                    }

                    else if(key > position)
                    {
                        dataObj[''+(parseInt(key)+1)] = dataObj[key]; /*push the rest*/
                    }

            });
```

and inject it back with `(this.treeData = dataObj;)` when it has injected the desired key and has shifted the rest by adding 1 to their keys when this is clicked:

```
<button type="button" v-on:click="injectFieldType('image','2')">
```

I need to have `{"post":{"1":{"title":{"name":"","intro":""}},"2":{"image":{"class":"default-image-class","creditto":""}},"3":{"paragraph":{"text":"","fontweight":"default-weight"....`   When I try to inject the image field in-between the existing "name" and "paragraph" fields and make the paragraph key now 3 (instead of the old 2).

I want `"{1:{foo}, 2:{bar}"}` to become => `{"1:{foo}, 2:{moo}, 3:{bar}" }`(notice 3 changed key)

NOTE: the number order is needed to align them reliably in publishing. And `data: {  treeData: myUserData.post }` needs to agree with the changes to allow creating the field and updating each form "name" attribute array.

Comment: `Vue.set(dataObj, ''+(parseInt(key)+1), dataObj[key])`

Comment: Mind you, the key (as you used above) is not to belong to the whole object set but each of the fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems to address here.

Firstly, trying to use `var dataObj = this.treeData;` and then `this.treeData = dataObj` isn't going to help. Both `dataObj` and `this.treeData` refer to the same object and that object has already been processed by Vue's reactivity system. You could address the reactivity problems by creating a totally new object but just creating an alias to the existing object won't help.

Instead of creating a new object I've chosen to use `this.$set` in my example. This isn't necessary for most of the properties, only the new one added at the end really needs it. However, it would have been unnecessarily complicated to single out that one property given the algorithm I've chosen to use.

Another potential problem is ensuring all numbers are compared as numbers and not as strings. In your example you're passing in the `position` as the string `'2'`. Operators such as `<` will give you the expected answer for numbers up to `9` but once the number of items in `treeData` reaches `10` you may start to run into problems. For string comparision `'2' < '10'` is `false`.

The next problem is the order you're moving the entries. In your current algorithm you're overwriting entry `key + 1` with entry `key`. But that means you've lost the original value for entry `key + 1`. You'll end up just copying the same entry all the way to the end. There are two ways you could fix this. One would be to use a new object to hold the output (which would also help to address the reactivity problem). In my solution below I've instead chosen to iterate backwards through the keys.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  data () {
    return {
      newEntry: 'Yellow',
      newIndex: 4,
      
      treeData: {
        1: 'Red',
        2: 'Green',
        3: 'Blue'
      }
    }
  },
  
  computed: {
    treeDataLength () {
      return Math.max(...Object.keys(this.treeData))
    }
  },
  
  methods: {
    onAddClick () {
      const newIndex = Math.round(this.newIndex)
      
      if (newIndex < 1 || newIndex > this.treeDataLength + 1) {
        return
      }

      this.injectFieldType(this.newEntry, newIndex)
    },
    
    injectFieldType (type, position) {
      const list = this.treeData
      
      for (let index = this.treeDataLength + 1; index >= position; --index) {
        if (index === position) {
          this.$set(list, index, type)
        } else {
          this.$set(list, index, list[index - 1])
        }
      }    
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="index in treeDataLength">
      {{ index}}. {{ treeData[index] }}
    </li>
  </ul>
  <input v-model="newEntry">
  <input v-model="newIndex">
  <button @click="onAddClick">Add</button>
</div>
```

The decision to use an object with number keys seems very strange. This would all be a lot easier if you just used an array.

Comment: Your answer has revealed to me the flaws in my code. I've tried it and it's working perfectly. I hope to refactor mine to follow the pattern you used above.